# Верно ли расставлены запятые в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Срок подачи до 10 сентября 2018 г. члену правления Петрову И.С., по воскресеньям с 10 до 11 часов, в беседке общества.

Answer (score 4):

Заявления (указать какие) принимает член правления И. С. Петров по воскресеньям,  с 10 до 11 часов, в беседке общества.

Срок подачи  до 10 сентября 2018 года.

Comment: _Срок подачи до_ — мне слышится тире или двоеточие перед "до". Поиск находит примерно поровну всех вариантов (без знака, двоеточие, тире). Это на выбор автора?

Comment: Думаю, что на выбор.  В данном случае использовано оформление простого (нераспространенного) предложения эллиптического вида  (подлежащее - обстоятельство), тире в этом случае факультативно, зависит от наличия паузы. Двоеточие можно поставить, если перечисляются  несколько позиций (форма подачи, срок подачи и т.д.).

Answer (score 0):

Предложение требует переделки. В исходном виде его не спасут никакие запятые.
Как вариант:

**Срок подачи (указать, чего) — до 10 сентября 2018 г. Прием (указать, чего) проводит член правления Петров И. С. по воскресеньям с 10 до 11 часов в беседке общества.**

- Желательно указать, о подаче и приеме чего идет речь, даже если это ясно из контекста.
- В написании инициалов нужен пробел после первой точки.
- Запятые опциональны. Я бы предпочел вариант без запятых (неоднородные     обстоятельства). Можно (но не обязательно) считать некоторые обстоятельства  уточнением, тогда запятые нужны, чтобы обособить уточняющие члены предложения.